# Load bash aliases when using submodule foreach

Tags: git, bash, git-submodules

Is there a way to make git source my `.bashaliases` file by default when running the `git submodule foreach` command?

For example, I've aliased `git --no-pager grep -n` to `ggrep`, and I frequently want to search all submodules with `git submodule foreach "ggrep <PATTERN>; true"`, but the command simply prints "ggrep: not found" for each submodule.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use an alias in the first place… make this `ggrep` an executable script (in a directory listed in your `PATH` variable).

Comment: *nod*. aliases are turned off by default in noninteractive shells. Sure, you *could* turn them on... but better to just do something with fewer surprises involved. Even an exported function would fall into that category, though how well that works depends on who your `/bin/sh` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases aren't intended for noninteractive use, and even if they *were* sourced into the shell being used in question, they still wouldn't be available in this context without being explicitly turned on *for that shell* with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

---

#### Using an Alias Anyhow

If you *really* want to do this with an alias, though, you can do that. In your `~/.bash_profile`, put something like the following:

```
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.env ENV=$HOME/.env
```

...and, in `~/.env`:

```
# attempt to enable expand_aliases only if current shell provides shopt
if command -v shopt; then
  shopt -s expand_aliases
fi

alias ggrep='git --no-pager grep -n'
```

---

#### Using an Exported Function

If your `/bin/sh` is provided by bash, consider an exported function -- placing the following in your `~/.bash_profile`, as an example:

```
ggrep() { git --no-pager grep -n "$@"; }
export -f ggrep
```

(Unlike `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` is executed only on login shells; however, since this command exports contents into the environment, shells invoked as child processes will inherit such contents).

---

#### Using an External Script

If you don't have that guarantee, put a script in your PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git --no-pager grep -n "$@"
```

Note that the `/bin/sh` shebang is used here as it's liable to be a smaller, lighter shell than bash, and `exec` is used to avoid an extra `fork()` to run the command as a subprocess.

Comment: i ended up just creating a `ggrep-all` function (rather than try to pass my alias to submodule foreach), based on your warning and the comments -- but this answers the question perfectly. thank you.

Comment: As an aside, POSIX doesn't mandate that function names with dashes be valid -- underscores, while a bit uglier, are safer if you're trying to be portable.

Comment: oh, thank you for that tip. i've fixed it ("best practices" and all that).